# HOw to make the text repeat only once every for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt

for example I have the XML code like this:

```
<quotes>
  <quote>
    <character>
      <name>LA FEU</name>
    </character>
  </quote>

  <quote>
    <character>
      <name>LA FEU</name>
    </character>
  </quote>

   <quote>
    <character>
      <name>LA FEU</name>
    </character>
  </quote>
</quotes>
```

My XSLT code to transform this to HTML:

```
<html>
      <body>
        <pre>
            <xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
            <!--Output name of the character in underline-->
            Name of character: <xsl:apply-templates select="//name"/> 
          </xsl:for-each>

        </pre>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Output is like this: Name of character: LAFEULAFEULAFEU

HOw to make the NAME repeat only once every for-each? Would you please help me? THank you
FOr example Name of character: LAFEU
            Name of character: LAFEU

## Name of character: LAFEU

=================================================================================================

I would like to ask 1 more thing related to this question. 
IN case if CHARACTER is under QUOTES many layer, like this:

```
 <quotes>
      <quote>
        <!--play 1-->
        <play>
          <playtitle>All's Well That Ends Well</playtitle>
          <act>
            <acttitle>ACT IV</acttitle>
            <scene>
              <scenetitle>SCENE I</scenetitle>
              <speech>
                <name>
                  <name>LAFEU</name>
                </name>
................
```

HOw to refer to NAME in the For-each statement , I try this, but not work

```
    <xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
            <!--Output name of the character in underline-->
            Name of character: <xsl:value-of select="play/*/name"/> 
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Would you please help me with this? THank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote/character">
    <!--Output name of the character in underline-->
    Name of character: <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : this solutions is for avoiding doubles on an ordered set, i reread your question, and saw how i probably misinterpret.    I leave my answer here, becaust it at least show you how to get rid of an unneeded for-each construction.

The question you do aks however is of a level under beginner i'm afraid.  You should learn the basics first imo.  Right now you're asking : "do my work for me please".

chekc here first if i may suggest : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

like this :

NOTE : (almost) never use for-each!!!! certainly not here!!
[see here](http://peterhelsen.blogspot.com/2009/03/never-ever-use-xslfor-each-element.html)
If you insist on it however, you can use the same preceding-sibling logic if you want in a for-each close.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <pre>    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//quote[not(./character/name = preceding-sibling::quote/character/name)]/character/name" />    
      </pre>
    </body>
  </html> 
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
    <pre>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </pre>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! I have tried to make as few changes to your XSLT as possible to achieve the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <pre>
          <xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
            <!--Output name of the character in underline-->
            Name of character: <xsl:apply-templates select="character/name"/> 
          </xsl:for-each>
        </pre>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has the following output :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>
        Name of character: LA FEU
        Name of character: LA FEU
        Name of character: LA FEU
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out good way to deal with this problem: using apply templates, thank you you guys very much :).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!--Handle the document: set up HTML page-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <pre>
          THIS IS ANOTHER TEST
          <!--Display number of quotes in the document-->
          There is <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/quote)"/> quotes in the document       
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </pre>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--Create the title for the play-->
  <xsl:template match="playtitle">
    Play title: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--Create the title for the scene-->
  <xsl:template match="scenetitle">
    Scene title: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--create the title for act-->
  <xsl:template match="acttitle">
   Act title: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--create the name for the character-->
  <xsl:template match="name">
     Character name: <span style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>   
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--create the text for the quote-->
  <xsl:template match="line">
         Quote text:
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```