# problem with using XPath to locate some part of XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

#### Duplicate of

> [HOw to make the text repeat only once every for-each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737091/how-to-make-the-text-repeat-only-once-every-for-each)

I have problem with using XPATH to point to some element in XML. 
Here is my XML code:

```
    <character>
      <name>some name </some name>
    </character>

  </quote>
 <quote>
  ....
  </quote>
 </quotes>
```

and here My XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
    <xsl:value-of select="quotes/quote/character/name"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

WHat I try to do is that I try to list the name of character for every quote.
BUt this code does not work 
WOuld you please help me with this problem? Thank you

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737091/how-to-make-the-text-repeat-only-once-every-for-each ??

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `for-each`, the context node is `quote` - so it *looks* like you just need:

```
<xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
    <xsl:value-of select="character/name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Of course, the purists would argue that it would be better to use a `match`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="quotes/quote" />
...
<xsl:template match="quote">
    <xsl:value-of select="character/name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:
You use **quotes/quote** twice

You might try this one:

```
<xsl:for-each select="quotes/quote">
  <xsl:value-of select="character/name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```