# Loading attribute in XPATH, problem

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I've got a question about loading attribute in XPATH.
I write short XML code to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testDate.xsl"?>
<element attribute="1/1/2100">
  Hung
 </element>
```

My XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!--Handle the document: set up HTML page-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>    
    </head>
    <body>
   This is a test   
     <xsl:value-of select="element@attribute"/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why it produces an error when loading the stylesheet? Would you please help me explain this? Thank you

Comment: It would be useful to see the error you're getting

Comment: You are asking so elementary questions similar to "Why when I touch a naked wire I felt pain and almost died?". Better start reading and learning. You desparately need to read a good book on XPath and XSLT.

Comment: could not agree more dimitre, and not the first time!!
I wrote in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737091/how-to-make-the-text-repeat-only-once-every-for-each : 
The question you do aks however is of a level under beginner i'm afraid. You should learn the basics first imo. Right now you're asking

Comment: do my work for me please!  Dear Nguyen, do yourself a favor and start learning!!

Comment: I am also doing learning at the same time with asking questions. I ask questions after I try many times, but it still does not work. So I ask for help by asking questions. It's like try some practice and receive feedback from other people, and it's really useful. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a slash before the `@` in your `<xsl:value-of />`.

You're getting an error because `element@attribute` is not valid XPath.  Putting the slash in indicates that you want to:

- find elements called `element`, and then
- within these elements, find an attribute called `attribute`.

The following amended stylesheet works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!--Handle the document: set up HTML page-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>    
    </head>
    <body>
                This is a test                  
        <xsl:value-of select="element/@attribute"/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your XPath for attribute is wrong. I think it should be

```
element/@attribute
```

i.e. you should separate element and @attribute with a /